# Windows Command: wmic memphysical get MaxCapacity - Does this show maximum RAM of each module?

Tags: laptop, memory

I am planning to upgrade RAM for my HP Pavilion X-360, it already has 16 GB RAM in one of the two slots. The sales person told it supports 32GB in each of the modules, so I am planning to add 32 GB in empty module. When I checked with HP support they say it supports only 16 GB max per module. When I run the command `wmic memphysical get MaxCapacity` it gives me the following output

```
C:\Users\Javed>wmic memphysical get MaxCapacity, MemoryDevices
MaxCapacity  MemoryDevices
33554432     2
```

Does the above output means 32 GB support is for each module (so 32 + 32 GB Support) or 32 GB is the maximum supported for both memory modules. Any suggestion in this regards is highly appreciated

Comment: "Maximum Memory: 16GB" from https://uk.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/hp---compaq/hp-pavilion-x360-convertible-(intel-5th-6th-gen)

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the total maximum capacity i.e 32GB. Since you have 2 slots, each module slot will support a maximum of 16GB.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?